# Does $2x^5 - x^4 - 22x^3 - 23x^2 + 22x +24 = 0$ have exact solutions in radicals?

Tags: polynomials, radicals

> Does $2x^5 - x^4 - 22x^3 - 23x^2 + 22x +24 = 0$ have exact solutions in radicals?

A mysterious commenter said on Youtube this was the "easiest quintic equation of my life," and I'm suspecting a troll is afoot. In fact, I believe the opposite is true, this is unsolvable in radicals and you need to prove it.

[Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/polynomial-equation-calculator/2x%5E%7B5%7D%20-%20x%5E%7B4%7D%20-%2022x%5E%7B3%7D%20-%2023x%5E%7B2%7D%20%2B%2022x%20%2B24%20%3D%200) gave up.

Update: Aahaan now says "bro i just took a bunch of linear equations and multiplied them to get this. Now we can factor it into them." The similar equation

$$x^5 - 2x^4 - 22x^3 - 23x^2 + 22x +24 = 0$$

has roots $-2, 1$ and reduces to a straightforward after polynomial division, so there might've been a typo.

Comment: Maybe you could tell the rest of us who this Aahaan Chawla is supposed to be. The source of the problem is useful

Comment: @Deepak Source is the comments section of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KpLaubCWSo4&lc=UgwFhGhk5v4cc2N58p54AaABAg.9LYmNB90EXY9LZSJ6SQn8y

Comment: OK so some random comment on an unrelated youtube video. Yeah, I wouldn't lose sleep over it.

Comment: I suspect the commentator made a mistake and noted for $1$ and $-1$ that except for $2x^5$ the even terms and the odd terms "cancel out" and he overlooked that $2x^5$ throws a monkey wrench.

Comment: By the rational root theorem, it's trivial to check whether this polynomial is the product of linear factors with rational coefficients.

Comment: Modulo $p=3$ it is the product of a linear polynomial and an irreducible quartic. Modulo $p=5$ it is the product of a quadratic and a cubic, both irreducible. Therefore Dedekind implies that the Galois group is $S_5$. Not solvable in radicals.

Answer (score 1):

Your polynomial $2x^5-x^4-22x^3-23x^2+22x+24$ has no solution in radical it's Galois group is the symmetric group if $5$ objects, on the other hard, $x^5-2x^4-22x^3-23x^2+22x+24$ factors into $(x-1)(x+2)(x^3-3x^2-17x-12)$

Since the polynomials are related in shape
$$2x^5-x^4-22x^3-23x^2+22x+24 = x^5-2x^4-22x^3-23x^2+22x+24 +(x^5+x^4)$$
$$2x^5-x^4-22x^3-23x^2+22x+24 = (x-1)(x+2)(x^3-3x^2-17x-12)+x^4(x+1)$$
There is no common linear factor, I believe it's a typo